# Adding an image to HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an image, but it only shows up as a corrupted or unloaded image(I'm not sure what to call it, it's a tiny picture of a broken picture..? lol) here is my code....

```
<img src="funny_alien_01.jpg05e9a40c-bb67-46e2-a106-ac097b47bd28Original.jpg">
```

I've tried this with an image from placeholder and that works fine, I'm wondering how to use an image off of google images or an image saved to my PC. Thanks.

Comment: Umm.. where is your code, @Eddie?

Comment: Most likely, the src you're giving is incorrect.

Comment: Please add your code. My guess is that your source (src) is incorrect. Try it with the src image in the same directory as your html file.

Comment: Look at it in the developer tools network panel and see what it says. My guess is a 404. Also does it load if you hit the image directly in the browser?

Comment: This looks like at least two links to images got mangled. The general debugging approach is to paste the url into the address bar, possibly adding the server part, and see what (and if) gets displayed

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you image source link
2. Give a readable image name. Like: 1.jpg or 1.png

Answer (score 0):

The path to the image in your example looks invalid.

To display an image from the web, you’ll need to use an absolute path:

`<img src="https://www.example.com/images/dinosaur.jpg">`

Notice how the path starts with `https://`

Check out this resource on how to use the image tag for displaying images from the web, or from your computer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML